# 403 Error for user verification (API)

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-status-code-403, user-accounts, staging

I have an Web application that require users to verify their email account after registration.  It works when we run it locally and current server.

However when we migrate it to the a staging server, the verification brings the below error.

POST http://www.XXXXXXXXX.org/api/account/verify 403 (Forbidden)

Can i ask if anyone have any idea on this?

Thank you!
Jo

Comment: this is an authentication error. if I were to guess I would say that in development you don't have any auth and in staging you do have it

Comment: Thanks Mircea.  Can i ask in staging where the authorisation comes from?  We pull the codes from the same bitbucket so supposed not related to the source code?

Comment: i cannot answer this since I don't know how you're deploying. what stack are you using for your service?

Comment: Mircea, I'm using mean stack.  I deploy it by doing gitpull from the bitbucket (of same source code of local) and then run forever start gulp again